# aspects, exceptionhandlers don't catch exception java spring

Tags: java, spring, exception, telegram, aop

annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface BotExceptionCheck {

}
```

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class BotExceptionCheckAspect {
    SendMessageProducer sendMessageProducer;
    UserService userService;

    public BotExceptionCheckAspect(SendMessageProducer sendMessageProducer, UserService userService) {
        this.sendMessageProducer = sendMessageProducer;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Around("@annotation(BotExceptionCheck)")
    public Object handleException(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object result = null;
        try {
            result = joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (BotAuthorizeException ex) {
            var user = userService.findById(ex.getChatId());
            sendMessageProducer.sendMessage(SendMessage.builder()
                    .chatId(user.getChatId())
                    .text(ex.getMessage())
                    .build());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

method where throw exception

```
  @BotExceptionCheck
    public void checkSubscriptionForChannel(ChatMember chatMember) {
        if (chatMember.getStatus().equals("kicked") || chatMember.getStatus().equals("left")) {
            throw new BotAuthorizeException(String.valueOf(chatMember.getUser().getId()), """
                    You don't subscribe to the channel
                    """);
        }
    }
```

also i try write exception handler, but it don't see exception too

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    SendMessageProducer sendMessageProducer;
    UserService userService;

    public GlobalExceptionHandler(SendMessageProducer sendMessageProducer, UserService userService) {
        this.sendMessageProducer = sendMessageProducer;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(BotAuthorizeException.class)
    public void handleBotAuthorizeException(BotAuthorizeException ex){
        var user = userService.findById(ex.getChatId());
        sendMessageProducer.sendMessage(SendMessage.builder()
                .chatId(user.getChatId())
                .text(ex.getMessage())
                .build());
    }
}
```

EXCEPTION that i get in all of this situation :
2023-08-12 10:15:54.070 ERROR 11228 --- [legram Executor] o.t.t.u.DefaultBotSession                : You don't subscribe to the channel.

com.moviescreenbot.exceptions.authorize.BotAuthorizeException: You don't subscribe to the channel.

```
at com.moviescreenbot.services.user.UserService.checkSubscriptionForChannel(UserService.java:53) ~[main/:na]
at com.moviescreenbot.services.user.UserService.authorizeUser(UserService.java:24) ~[main/:na]
at com.moviescreenbot.services.user.UserService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$64cf6081.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at com.moviescreenbot.services.user.UserService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6ca7934e.authorizeUser(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
```

help to resolve this problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: See, the problem with a bunch of snippets instead of full classes with package names and imports plus a Spring configuration or - even better - a link to a minimal reproducer on GitHub is, that there are so many ways to get Spring AOP wrong: configuration, self-invocation, trying to target something other than a Spring-managed bean, mixing native AspectJ with Spring AOP. The people trying to help you would have to guess.